Uncensored auto-captioning libraries that work well for NSFW image datasets?
I have a large (>2.5 million files) dataset of NSFW images that I would like to auto-generate detailed (~100-150 token) captions for, using a visual language model similar to CogVLM or Llava.
I have tried both CogVLM and Llava, and unfortunately both models are far too heavily censored to complete the task. The responses range either from outright refusal to caption the images, or captions that are so heavily filtered for "appropriateness" that they fail to describe the important features of the image. Also, it appears that they struggle to comprehend the actual contents of the images, due to having a skewed training dataset that deliberately excluded this class of images.
I am wondering if there are any image understanding models that work in a similar way to CogVLM but that are less heavily censored and work well with captioning NSFW images and are comfortable writing output with "vulgar" language? Basically, I want to provide a text prompt (e.g. "Describe what these people are doing in this image.") and an image file, and have the model provide a caption with the specified # of tokens.
Or alternatively, if there are no such models that already exist, do you know of any work that people have done to create fine-tunes of CogVLM/Llava that would work for this purpose, and what this fine tuning process would look like for the task described above? Thanks!
